# Using HLF peers for off ledger communication

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I would like to leverage Hyperledger Fabric Peers (specifically identities) to communicate data that does not need to be recorded as a world state.
The Private Data Collection seems a step in that direction but everything is ordered and recorded.
Is there a way to **send a payload between participants** that does not get persisted?

Answer (score 2):

Of course, every parameter sent is recorded in the channel's chain (but not in the world state unless your chaincode specifically does it).

Maybe you can save the payload (encrypted if you need it) in a distributed storage system (IPFS, for instance), share the IPFS hash/index via Fabric and delete from IPFS when it is no longer needed. I don't know if it fits your use case.

Comment: Since the payload would not be transiting through Peers you need a separate transport. But it's a valid workaround thanks.